# Phrases meaning "in the bad old days"?

Tags: phrase-request

[It is said](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/in-the-old-days) that "in the old days" means especially "in the **good** old days". But are there any phrases meaning the opposite(bad old days)? When things were very tough and/or primitive/**antediluvian**?

I can think of "in the iron age", but I'd like to know if there exist other common sayings which are more native.

Comment: I have heard it phrased exactly that way: "in the bad old days."

Comment: I thought "primordial" would be a good match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard times.

Those were hard times back then.

To have it tough.

My grandparents had it tough.

Answer (score 1):

"Back in cave-man days"

"Back in the stone age"

"Back in the Dark Ages"

"Medieval."

"When I was a kid, we had to walk to school.  On a dirt road.  Uphill.  Both ways.  In the snow."

Answer (score 0):

I've heard "bad old days" used from time to time, in a deliberate/humorous inversion of "good old days".

"Back in the dark ages" is more established, and does not necessarily refer to the historical period called The Dark Ages.

Answer (score -2):

"In the days of yore when bastards ruled the roost". Colloquial.